# C3js - Show circle only at the last point of the graph

Tags: c3.js

My chart currently has all the hidden points (the points I'm referring to are "balls" circles), but I need them to show the ball only at the last point.

Look at this image to see exactly what I need.

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEed5.jpg)

As you can see, all the dots "balls" are hidden, except the last one.

I took a look at the C3js material, but found nothing that would help me with that.

Does anyone know how I can do this?

My current code.

```js
var area_chart = c3.generate({
            bindto: '#chart',
            size: { height: 350, width: 800 },
            point: {
                show: false
            },
            color: {
                pattern: ['#000', '#E53935']
            },
            data: {
                columns: [
                    ['Meta', 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300],
                    ['Produção', 200, 280, 280, 280, 260, 260, 260, 260, 270, 270, 270, 270, 270, 230, 240, 280, 300],
                ],
                types: {
                    Produção: 'area-spline',
                }
            },
            axis: {
                x: {
                    type: 'category',
                    categories: ['08:00', '08:30', '09:00', '09:30', '10:00', '10:30', '11:00', '11:30', '12:00', '12:30', '13:00', '13:30', '14:00', '14:30', '15:00', '15:30', '16:00', '16:30'],
                    tick: {
                        rotate: 60,
                        multiline: false
                    },
                }
            },
            grid: {
                x: {
                    show: true
                },
                y: {
                    show: true
                }
            }
        });
```

```html
<div id="chart"></div>
```

[CODE](https://jsfiddle.net/9428n6br/1/)

Comment: If you found my answer useful please could you mark it as the correct answer so that other users can judge its relevance - thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you open the chart in your browsers DOM inspector you can drill into the chart and see the structure.  You can then use your favourite DOM manipulation library - I use jquery in my example, find the circles and hide them except the last.

I would have included a working snippet since it is so trivial but SO throws a script error, so [here is a pen](https://codepen.io/JEE42/pen/OBZxjj).

The important line is this. Note that you should start your search from a known element - preferably the chart container, so that you don't randomly kill bobbles on other charts on the same page. Put this line after your C3 generate command.

```
$('#chart').find('.c3-circle:not(:last)').css({opacity: 0})
```

Libraries like jquery can sound like a big learning exercise, but you can learn about simple DOM sniping like this without much time investment.

Comment: hi, I could not do it the way you posted it, I made some changes and it worked. I do it in other CSS .c3-circle:not(:last-child){
  display:none;
}

Comment: Cool - the css is likely to vary a bit in the final selectors as you have found. Happy to show you the way.